# Write a function to insert a value at a given position in a vector

Tags: r

I'm looking to write a function named `insert(x, where, what)` that inserts a value (`what`) at a given position (`where`) in a vector (`x`)

If the given position exceeds the dimension of a vector there should be a warning message that prints out and the positions between the last element of the vector and the inserted value should be filled with NAs

This is what I have so far but it results in a vertical vector:

```
    x <- 1:10
insert <- function (x, where, what)
  {if (where>10) c(append(x, what, after = where-1),print("Warning message: In insert(a, 11 , 0) : 11 exceeds the dimensions of the vector"))
  else
    append(x, what, after = where-1)}


insert(x, 5, 0)
insert(x, 11, 0)
insert(x,15,0)
```

Below is the desired output:

```
    a <- 1:10

insert(a, 5, 0) 
[1] 1 2 3 4 0 5 6 7 8 9 10

insert(a, 11, 0) 
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 0 
Warning message: 
In insert(a, 11, 0) : 11 exceeds the dimension of the vector

insert(a, 15, 0) 
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 NA NA NA NA 0 
Warning message: 
In insert(a, 15, 0) : 15 exceeds the dimension of the vector
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach to achieve your desired result may look like so:

```r
insert <- function(x, where, what) {
  lenx <- length(x)
  if (where > lenx) {
    warning(paste0(where, " exceeds the dimensions of the vector."))
    res <- c(x, rep(NA, where - lenx - 1), what)
  } else {
    res <- c(x[seq(where - 1)], what, x[seq(where, lenx)])
  }
  return(res)
}

x <- 1:10

insert(x, 5, 0)
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  0  5  6  7  8  9 10
insert(x, 11, 0)
#> Warning in insert(x, 11, 0): 11 exceeds the dimensions of the vector.
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  0
insert(x, 15, 0)
#> Warning in insert(x, 15, 0): 15 exceeds the dimensions of the vector.
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 NA NA NA NA  0
```

Comment: This makes so much more sense! Thank you so much!